# No module named sqlite3 exception

Tags: python, sqlite, visual-c++, boost

I'm using `boost::python` in my Visual C++ application and I have a script that wants to connect to an SQLite database and read some data from it.

In my script, I imported `sqlite3` and it works fine when I run it with Python IDLE but, when it runs inside my Visual C++ application, I get an exception:

> No module named _sqlite3

Can anyone tell me why it happens? What did I miss here?

Even this line in my code returns the same exception:

```
boost::python::object objSQLite3 = boost::python::import("sqlite3");
```

Comment: `No module named sqlite3` or `No module named _sqlite3`?

Comment: @ Kevin Guan : No module named _sqlite3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem!!!

I install the `python` via `inno setup` in silent mode. For first time since there is no `python` on system all libraries copy successfully But if u do it again since it try to install `python` again `(/i)`, It some how mess with some library like `sqlite3`.

So u need change your `inno setup` script to reinstall the `python` if it exists `(/a)`.

PS : If you have this problem and you don't use `inno setup` just reinstall your `python` to fix this problem.

Best Regards